# Can I get the approximated travel time from directions I already have on a mapView?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I am trying to display the approximate travel time to a location from the user's current location with directions already appearing on the map. I am wondering if this is possible as nothing seems to come up online when I search this. If it is possible swift would be better than Objective-C.

Comment: No, you cannot since travel time depends on the travel speed and the travel distance.  You can find the distance to your destination so that you can update the arrival time.

Comment: if i were to find the travel distance would I be able to find the estimated travel time?

Comment: I think you can estimate the current travel speed with `CLLocationManager`.   But I have never done it for myself.  So I cannot definitely say yes or no.

Comment: Approximated travel time by what? e.g. walking, car, train?
If you know the speed, you can find out the estimate time. (Objective-C/Swift should not be an issue)
I think google also provide some API support to calculate time, you can check that, if you want to use their API. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start

Comment: I would primarily like to know the speed by car. Is there any way of using apple maps instead of google?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already showing directions on map, and your requirement is to use Apple maps. I think you are using `MKDirectionsRequest` to get and show directions. Using `MKDirectionsRequest` you can find the directions and possible routes. You can specify  which type of directions are required (automobile, transit, walking) and from `route` you can get the estimated travel time. For your convenience I am adding the complete code.

```
        let request = MKDirectionsRequest()
        request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: startLocation?.latitude, longitude: startLocation?.longitude), addressDictionary: nil))
        request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: endLocation?.latitude, longitude: endLocation?.longitude), addressDictionary: nil))
        request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true // if you want multiple possible routes
        request.transportType = .automobile  // will be good for cars
```

Now get the directions

```
        let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
        directions.calculate {(response, error) -> Void in

            guard let response = response else {
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
                return
            }

          // Lets Get the first suggested route and its travel time

           if response.routes.count > 0 {
                let route = response.routes[0]
                print(route.expectedTravelTime) // it will be in seconds
                // you can show this time in any of your UILabel or whatever you want. 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works really well! Didn't know it could be so simple!

Comment: glad to help you out.